# How to load data into a component using Inertia?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, inertiajs

I got a simple component:

```html
<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue'

const labels = []
</script>

<template>
<div v-for="(label, index) in labels" :key="index" v-html="label"></div>
</template>
```

I want to use this Component inside an `<aside>` block showing "side information". This Component should get its own data, independent from the parent element, so that I can add it wherever I want.

I understand how I create a "full page" component where I pass the data with `inertia('Page', ['lables' => ['Foo', 'Bar']])` from the controller to the vue component.

But I don't understand how I would do it for that "side" component.

I already added a route to an invokable controller, that would pass the data as json, but this would force me to load the data with axios "the usual vue way".

Now I'm wondering, how I would do it with inertia. I know, there are manual visits using `router` from `inertiajs/vue`, but the `get` method is more like "navigating away" instead of "fetching data".

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Shared data](https://inertiajs.com/shared-data):

```php
// HandleInertiaRequests.php
public function share(Request $request)
{
    return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
        'labels' => ['Foo', 'Bar'],
        ...
    ]);
}
```

```html
<!-- Vue component -->
<script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue'
import { usePage } from '@inertiajs/vue3'

const page = usePage()

const labels = computed(() => page.props.labels)
</script>


<template>
    <div v-for="(label, index) in labels" :key="index" v-html="label"></div>
</template>
```